# K3d gives "Error response from daemon: invalid reference format" error

Tags: k3s, k3d

I'm trying to run k3d with a previous version of k8s (v1.20.2, which matches the current version of k8s on OVH).  I understand that the correct way of doing this is to specify the image of k3s in the config file.  Running this fails with: `Error response from daemon: invalid reference format`  (full logs below).

How can I avoid this error?

Command:

```sh
k3d cluster create bitbuyer-cluster --config ./k3d-config.yml
```

Config:

```yaml
# k3d-config.yml
apiVersion: k3d.io/v1alpha3
kind: Simple
# version for k8s v1.20.2
image: rancher/k3s:v1.20.11+k3s2
options:
  k3s:
    extraArgs:
      - arg: "--kubelet-arg=eviction-hard=imagefs.available<1%,nodefs.available<1%"
        nodeFilters:
          - server:*
      - arg: "--kubelet-arg=eviction-minimum-reclaim=imagefs.available=1%,nodefs.available=1%"
        nodeFilters:
          - server:*
```

Logs:

```
# $ k3d cluster create bitbuyer-cluster --trace --config ./k3d-config.yml
DEBU[0000] Runtime Info:
&{Name:docker Endpoint:/var/run/docker.sock Version:20.10.9 OSType:linux OS:Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Arch:x86_64 CgroupVersion:1 CgroupDriver:cgroupfs Filesystem:extfs} 
DEBU[0000] Additional CLI Configuration:
cli:
  api-port: ""
  env: []
  k3s-node-labels: []
  k3sargs: []
  ports: []
  registries:
    create: ""
  runtime-labels: []
  volumes: [] 
DEBU[0000] Validating file ./k3d-config.yml against default JSONSchema... 
DEBU[0000] JSON Schema Validation Result: &{errors:[] score:62} 
INFO[0000] Using config file ./k3d-config.yml (k3d.io/v1alpha3#simple) 
DEBU[0000] Configuration:
agents: 0
apiversion: k3d.io/v1alpha3
image: rancher/k3s:v1.20.11+k3s2
kind: Simple
network: ""
options:
  k3d:
    disableimagevolume: false
    disableloadbalancer: false
    disablerollback: false
    loadbalancer:
      configoverrides: []
    timeout: 0s
    wait: true
  k3s:
    extraargs:
    - arg: --kubelet-arg=eviction-hard=imagefs.available<1%,nodefs.available<1%
      nodeFilters:
      - server:*
    - arg: --kubelet-arg=eviction-minimum-reclaim=imagefs.available=1%,nodefs.available=1%
      nodeFilters:
      - server:*
  kubeconfig:
    switchcurrentcontext: true
    updatedefaultkubeconfig: true
  runtime:
    agentsmemory: ""
    gpurequest: ""
    serversmemory: ""
registries:
  config: ""
  use: []
servers: 1
subnet: ""
token: "" 
TRAC[0000] Trying to read config apiVersion='k3d.io/v1alpha3', kind='simple' 
DEBU[0000] ========== Simple Config ==========
{TypeMeta:{Kind:Simple APIVersion:k3d.io/v1alpha3} Name: Servers:1 Agents:0 ExposeAPI:{Host: HostIP: HostPort:} Image:rancher/k3s:v1.20.11+k3s2 Network: Subnet: ClusterToken: Volumes:[] Ports:[] Options:{K3dOptions:{Wait:true Timeout:0s DisableLoadbalancer:false DisableImageVolume:false NoRollback:false NodeHookActions:[] Loadbalancer:{ConfigOverrides:[]}} K3sOptions:{ExtraArgs:[{Arg:--kubelet-arg=eviction-hard=imagefs.available<1%,nodefs.available<1% NodeFilters:[server:*]} {Arg:--kubelet-arg=eviction-minimum-reclaim=imagefs.available=1%,nodefs.available=1% NodeFilters:[server:*]}] NodeLabels:[]} KubeconfigOptions:{UpdateDefaultKubeconfig:true SwitchCurrentContext:true} Runtime:{GPURequest: ServersMemory: AgentsMemory: Labels:[]}} Env:[] Registries:{Use:[] Create:<nil> Config:}}
========================== 
TRAC[0000] VolumeFilterMap: map[]                       
TRAC[0000] PortFilterMap: map[]                         
TRAC[0000] K3sNodeLabelFilterMap: map[]                 
TRAC[0000] RuntimeLabelFilterMap: map[]                 
TRAC[0000] EnvFilterMap: map[]                          
DEBU[0000] ========== Merged Simple Config ==========
{TypeMeta:{Kind:Simple APIVersion:k3d.io/v1alpha3} Name: Servers:1 Agents:0 ExposeAPI:{Host: HostIP: HostPort:43681} Image:rancher/k3s:v1.20.11+k3s2 Network: Subnet: ClusterToken: Volumes:[] Ports:[] Options:{K3dOptions:{Wait:true Timeout:0s DisableLoadbalancer:false DisableImageVolume:false NoRollback:false NodeHookActions:[] Loadbalancer:{ConfigOverrides:[]}} K3sOptions:{ExtraArgs:[{Arg:--kubelet-arg=eviction-hard=imagefs.available<1%,nodefs.available<1% NodeFilters:[server:*]} {Arg:--kubelet-arg=eviction-minimum-reclaim=imagefs.available=1%,nodefs.available=1% NodeFilters:[server:*]}] NodeLabels:[]} KubeconfigOptions:{UpdateDefaultKubeconfig:true SwitchCurrentContext:true} Runtime:{GPURequest: ServersMemory: AgentsMemory: Labels:[]}} Env:[] Registries:{Use:[] Create:<nil> Config:}}
========================== 
DEBU[0000] generated loadbalancer config:
ports:
  6443.tcp:
  - k3d-bitbuyer-cluster-server-0
settings:
  workerConnections: 1024 
TRAC[0000] Filtering 2 nodes by [server:*]              
TRAC[0000] Filtered 1 nodes (filter: [server:*])        
TRAC[0000] Filtering 2 nodes by [server:*]              
TRAC[0000] Filtered 1 nodes (filter: [server:*])        
DEBU[0000] ===== Merged Cluster Config =====
&{TypeMeta:{Kind: APIVersion:} Cluster:{Name:bitbuyer-cluster Network:{Name:k3d-bitbuyer-cluster ID: External:false IPAM:{IPPrefix:zero IPPrefix IPsUsed:[] Managed:false} Members:[]} Token: Nodes:[0xc00019aa80 0xc00019ac00] InitNode:<nil> ExternalDatastore:<nil> KubeAPI:0xc000654240 ServerLoadBalancer:0xc0001de690 ImageVolume:} ClusterCreateOpts:{DisableImageVolume:false WaitForServer:true Timeout:0s DisableLoadBalancer:false GPURequest: ServersMemory: AgentsMemory: NodeHooks:[] GlobalLabels:map[app:k3d] GlobalEnv:[] Registries:{Create:<nil> Use:[] Config:<nil>}} KubeconfigOpts:{UpdateDefaultKubeconfig:true SwitchCurrentContext:true}}
===== ===== ===== 
DEBU[0000] ===== Processed Cluster Config =====
&{TypeMeta:{Kind: APIVersion:} Cluster:{Name:bitbuyer-cluster Network:{Name:k3d-bitbuyer-cluster ID: External:false IPAM:{IPPrefix:zero IPPrefix IPsUsed:[] Managed:false} Members:[]} Token: Nodes:[0xc00019aa80 0xc00019ac00] InitNode:<nil> ExternalDatastore:<nil> KubeAPI:0xc000654240 ServerLoadBalancer:0xc0001de690 ImageVolume:} ClusterCreateOpts:{DisableImageVolume:false WaitForServer:true Timeout:0s DisableLoadBalancer:false GPURequest: ServersMemory: AgentsMemory: NodeHooks:[] GlobalLabels:map[app:k3d] GlobalEnv:[] Registries:{Create:<nil> Use:[] Config:<nil>}} KubeconfigOpts:{UpdateDefaultKubeconfig:true SwitchCurrentContext:true}}
===== ===== ===== 
DEBU[0000] '--kubeconfig-update-default set: enabling wait-for-server 
INFO[0000] Prep: Network                                
DEBU[0000] Found network {Name:k3d-bitbuyer-cluster ID:f5217ad3aa1832d1e942dea8f624a5c48baa5f3009c88aa95fa0ee812108e384 Created:2021-10-15 12:56:38.391159451 +0100 WEST Scope:local Driver:bridge EnableIPv6:false IPAM:{Driver:default Options:map[] Config:[{Subnet:172.25.0.0/16 IPRange: Gateway:172.25.0.1 AuxAddress:map[]}]} Internal:false Attachable:false Ingress:false ConfigFrom:{Network:} ConfigOnly:false Containers:map[] Options:map[] Labels:map[app:k3d] Peers:[] Services:map[]} 
INFO[0000] Re-using existing network 'k3d-bitbuyer-cluster' (f5217ad3aa1832d1e942dea8f624a5c48baa5f3009c88aa95fa0ee812108e384) 
INFO[0000] Created volume 'k3d-bitbuyer-cluster-images' 
TRAC[0000] Using Registries: []                         
TRAC[0000] 
===== Creating Cluster =====

Runtime:
{}

Cluster:
&{Name:bitbuyer-cluster Network:{Name:k3d-bitbuyer-cluster ID:f5217ad3aa1832d1e942dea8f624a5c48baa5f3009c88aa95fa0ee812108e384 External:false IPAM:{IPPrefix:172.25.0.0/16 IPsUsed:[172.25.0.1] Managed:false} Members:[]} Token: Nodes:[0xc00019aa80 0xc00019ac00] InitNode:<nil> ExternalDatastore:<nil> KubeAPI:0xc000654240 ServerLoadBalancer:0xc0001de690 ImageVolume:k3d-bitbuyer-cluster-images}

ClusterCreatOpts:
&{DisableImageVolume:false WaitForServer:true Timeout:0s DisableLoadBalancer:false GPURequest: ServersMemory: AgentsMemory: NodeHooks:[] GlobalLabels:map[app:k3d k3d.cluster.imageVolume:k3d-bitbuyer-cluster-images k3d.cluster.network:k3d-bitbuyer-cluster k3d.cluster.network.external:true k3d.cluster.network.id:f5217ad3aa1832d1e942dea8f624a5c48baa5f3009c88aa95fa0ee812108e384 k3d.cluster.network.iprange:172.25.0.0/16] GlobalEnv:[] Registries:{Create:<nil> Use:[] Config:<nil>}}

============================
     
INFO[0000] Starting new tools node...                   
TRAC[0000] Creating node from spec
&{Name:k3d-bitbuyer-cluster-tools Role:noRole Image:docker.io/rancher/k3d-tools:5.0.1 Volumes:[k3d-bitbuyer-cluster-images:/k3d/images /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock] Env:[] Cmd:[] Args:[noop] Ports:map[] Restart:false Created: RuntimeLabels:map[app:k3d k3d.cluster:bitbuyer-cluster k3d.version:v5.0.1] K3sNodeLabels:map[] Networks:[k3d-bitbuyer-cluster] ExtraHosts:[] ServerOpts:{IsInit:false KubeAPI:<nil>} AgentOpts:{} GPURequest: Memory: State:{Running:false Status: Started:} IP:{IP:zero IP Static:false} HookActions:[]} 
TRAC[0000] Creating docker container with translated config
&{ContainerConfig:{Hostname:k3d-bitbuyer-cluster-tools Domainname: User: AttachStdin:false AttachStdout:false AttachStderr:false ExposedPorts:map[] Tty:false OpenStdin:false StdinOnce:false Env:[K3S_KUBECONFIG_OUTPUT=/output/kubeconfig.yaml] Cmd:[noop] Healthcheck:<nil> ArgsEscaped:false Image:docker.io/rancher/k3d-tools:5.0.1 Volumes:map[] WorkingDir: Entrypoint:[] NetworkDisabled:false MacAddress: OnBuild:[] Labels:map[app:k3d k3d.cluster:bitbuyer-cluster k3d.role:noRole k3d.version:v5.0.1] StopSignal: StopTimeout:<nil> Shell:[]} HostConfig:{Binds:[k3d-bitbuyer-cluster-images:/k3d/images /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock] ContainerIDFile: LogConfig:{Type: Config:map[]} NetworkMode: PortBindings:map[] RestartPolicy:{Name: MaximumRetryCount:0} AutoRemove:false VolumeDriver: VolumesFrom:[] CapAdd:[] CapDrop:[] CgroupnsMode: DNS:[] DNSOptions:[] DNSSearch:[] ExtraHosts:[] GroupAdd:[] IpcMode: Cgroup: Links:[] OomScoreAdj:0 PidMode: Privileged:true PublishAllPorts:false ReadonlyRootfs:false SecurityOpt:[] StorageOpt:map[] Tmpfs:map[/run: /var/run:] UTSMode: UsernsMode: ShmSize:0 Sysctls:map[] Runtime: ConsoleSize:[0 0] Isolation: Resources:{CPUShares:0 Memory:0 NanoCPUs:0 CgroupParent: BlkioWeight:0 BlkioWeightDevice:[] BlkioDeviceReadBps:[] BlkioDeviceWriteBps:[] BlkioDeviceReadIOps:[] BlkioDeviceWriteIOps:[] CPUPeriod:0 CPUQuota:0 CPURealtimePeriod:0 CPURealtimeRuntime:0 CpusetCpus: CpusetMems: Devices:[] DeviceCgroupRules:[] DeviceRequests:[] KernelMemory:0 KernelMemoryTCP:0 MemoryReservation:0 MemorySwap:0 MemorySwappiness:<nil> OomKillDisable:<nil> PidsLimit:<nil> Ulimits:[] CPUCount:0 CPUPercent:0 IOMaximumIOps:0 IOMaximumBandwidth:0} Mounts:[] MaskedPaths:[] ReadonlyPaths:[] Init:0xc00064d1cf} NetworkingConfig:{EndpointsConfig:map[k3d-bitbuyer-cluster:0xc0004da000]}} 
INFO[0001] Creating node 'k3d-bitbuyer-cluster-server-0' 
TRAC[0001] Creating node from spec
&{Name:k3d-bitbuyer-cluster-server-0 Role:server Image:rancher/k3s:v1.20.11+k3s2 Volumes:[k3d-bitbuyer-cluster-images:/k3d/images] Env:[K3S_TOKEN=QEQoybzqvqzTjQkBhTpz] Cmd:[] Args:[--kubelet-arg=eviction-hard=imagefs.available<1%,nodefs.available<1% --kubelet-arg=eviction-minimum-reclaim=imagefs.available=1%,nodefs.available=1%] Ports:map[] Restart:true Created: RuntimeLabels:map[app:k3d k3d.cluster:bitbuyer-cluster k3d.cluster.imageVolume:k3d-bitbuyer-cluster-images k3d.cluster.network:k3d-bitbuyer-cluster k3d.cluster.network.external:true k3d.cluster.network.id:f5217ad3aa1832d1e942dea8f624a5c48baa5f3009c88aa95fa0ee812108e384 k3d.cluster.network.iprange:172.25.0.0/16 k3d.cluster.token:QEQoybzqvqzTjQkBhTpz k3d.cluster.url:https://k3d-bitbuyer-cluster-server-0:6443] K3sNodeLabels:map[] Networks:[k3d-bitbuyer-cluster] ExtraHosts:[] ServerOpts:{IsInit:false KubeAPI:0xc000654240} AgentOpts:{} GPURequest: Memory: State:{Running:false Status: Started:} IP:{IP:zero IP Static:false} HookActions:[]} 
DEBU[0001] DockerHost:                                  
TRAC[0001] Creating docker container with translated config
&{ContainerConfig:{Hostname:k3d-bitbuyer-cluster-server-0 Domainname: User: AttachStdin:false AttachStdout:false AttachStderr:false ExposedPorts:map[] Tty:false OpenStdin:false StdinOnce:false Env:[K3S_TOKEN=QEQoybzqvqzTjQkBhTpz K3S_KUBECONFIG_OUTPUT=/output/kubeconfig.yaml] Cmd:[server --kubelet-arg=eviction-hard=imagefs.available<1%,nodefs.available<1% --kubelet-arg=eviction-minimum-reclaim=imagefs.available=1%,nodefs.available=1% --tls-san 0.0.0.0] Healthcheck:<nil> ArgsEscaped:false Image:rancher/k3s:v1.20.11+k3s2 Volumes:map[] WorkingDir: Entrypoint:[] NetworkDisabled:false MacAddress: OnBuild:[] Labels:map[app:k3d k3d.cluster:bitbuyer-cluster k3d.cluster.imageVolume:k3d-bitbuyer-cluster-images k3d.cluster.network:k3d-bitbuyer-cluster k3d.cluster.network.external:true k3d.cluster.network.id:f5217ad3aa1832d1e942dea8f624a5c48baa5f3009c88aa95fa0ee812108e384 k3d.cluster.network.iprange:172.25.0.0/16 k3d.cluster.token:QEQoybzqvqzTjQkBhTpz k3d.cluster.url:https://k3d-bitbuyer-cluster-server-0:6443 k3d.role:server k3d.server.api.host:0.0.0.0 k3d.server.api.hostIP:0.0.0.0 k3d.server.api.port:43681 k3d.version:v5.0.1] StopSignal: StopTimeout:<nil> Shell:[]} HostConfig:{Binds:[k3d-bitbuyer-cluster-images:/k3d/images] ContainerIDFile: LogConfig:{Type: Config:map[]} NetworkMode: PortBindings:map[] RestartPolicy:{Name:unless-stopped MaximumRetryCount:0} AutoRemove:false VolumeDriver: VolumesFrom:[] CapAdd:[] CapDrop:[] CgroupnsMode: DNS:[] DNSOptions:[] DNSSearch:[] ExtraHosts:[] GroupAdd:[] IpcMode: Cgroup: Links:[] OomScoreAdj:0 PidMode: Privileged:true PublishAllPorts:false ReadonlyRootfs:false SecurityOpt:[] StorageOpt:map[] Tmpfs:map[/run: /var/run:] UTSMode: UsernsMode: ShmSize:0 Sysctls:map[] Runtime: ConsoleSize:[0 0] Isolation: Resources:{CPUShares:0 Memory:0 NanoCPUs:0 CgroupParent: BlkioWeight:0 BlkioWeightDevice:[] BlkioDeviceReadBps:[] BlkioDeviceWriteBps:[] BlkioDeviceReadIOps:[] BlkioDeviceWriteIOps:[] CPUPeriod:0 CPUQuota:0 CPURealtimePeriod:0 CPURealtimeRuntime:0 CpusetCpus: CpusetMems: Devices:[] DeviceCgroupRules:[] DeviceRequests:[] KernelMemory:0 KernelMemoryTCP:0 MemoryReservation:0 MemorySwap:0 MemorySwappiness:<nil> OomKillDisable:<nil> PidsLimit:<nil> Ulimits:[] CPUCount:0 CPUPercent:0 IOMaximumIOps:0 IOMaximumBandwidth:0} Mounts:[] MaskedPaths:[] ReadonlyPaths:[] Init:0xc00035040f} NetworkingConfig:{EndpointsConfig:map[k3d-bitbuyer-cluster:0xc0003740c0]}} 
ERRO[0001] Failed Cluster Creation: failed setup of server/agent node k3d-bitbuyer-cluster-server-0: failed to create node: runtime failed to create node 'k3d-bitbuyer-cluster-server-0': failed to create container for node 'k3d-bitbuyer-cluster-server-0': docker failed to create container 'k3d-bitbuyer-cluster-server-0': Error response from daemon: invalid reference format 
ERRO[0001] Failed to create cluster >>> Rolling Back    
INFO[0001] Deleting cluster 'bitbuyer-cluster'          
ERRO[0001] failed to get cluster: No nodes found for given cluster 
FATA[0001] Cluster creation FAILED, also FAILED to rollback changes!
```

Kubectl:

```sh
# $ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.11", GitCommit:"27522a29febbcc4badac257763044d0d90c11abd", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-09-15T19:21:44Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```